# How to store the user id in session with ember-simple-auth?

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I want to store the user id in the session. I have this authenticate method in a custom authenticator :

```
authenticate: (credentials) ->
  _this = this
  new (Ember.RSVP.Promise) (resolve, reject) ->
    Ember.$.ajax(
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions'
      type: 'POST'
      data: session:
        email: credentials.identification
        password: credentials.password
    ).then ((response) ->
      _this.set('user_id', response.user_id)
      Ember.run ->
        resolve token: response.token
    ), (xhr, status, error) ->
      response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
      Ember.run ->
        reject response.error
```

It's coffee script but it works like javascript. As you can this, I set 'user_id' in the session.

In `app/initializers/custom-session`, I have this :

```
import Ember from "ember";
import Session from "simple-auth/session";

export default {
  name: "current-user",
  before: "simple-auth",
  initialize: function(container) {
    Session.reopen({
      setCurrentUser: function() {
        return this.get('user_id')
      }.observes('secure.access_token')
    });
  }
};
```

`user_id` always returns `undefined`. I found many solutions on the Internet but nothing works.

Is there a simple solution to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the `user_id` on the `authenticator` (`_this.set('user_id', response.user_id)`) instead of the `session`. The `user_id` should be passed to the resolve method in your `authenticator`. That way your user id is accessible by `secure.user_id` in your `session`.

Comment: I added a `then` callback to my authentication and it works. The only think I don't like is than the user id is gave by post request I made in the authenticator. I don't have access to it in my callback method. Do you know if it's possible to have information without to do a second request?

Comment: @Dougui What do you mean by callback method? Can you give an example?